# set field internal name with list.updatelist webservice

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, spfield

Is it possible to set a field's internal name in the List.UpdateList webservice? I can set the DisplayName but no matter what I try for Name it does not work.

```
<Field DisplayName="this gets set" Name="thisDoesNotSet" ... />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will not get set. Workaround is

1. Add field and set `DisplayName="thisDoesNotSet"`
2. Now SharePoint will set both Display and Internal to `thisDoesNotSet`
3. Update Display Name to `this gets set`

Comment: do you know if I can do that in one web service call or do i have to split it into two?

Comment: Split it into two service calls

Comment: it actually worked in one service call. newfields first with Method ID equal to 1, 2, 3 and then the updatefields with Method ID equal to 4, 5, 6.